# How to get Messages to connect to Facebook chat?

Tags: ichat, messages

I have the very same configuration for messages on two different Macs (home and work). At home I have no problem in connecting to the Facebook chat via the jabber protocol, while at work it simply doesn't connect and rises an error saying that it cannot connect to the host `chat.facebook.com`

I have no proxy problems here: I can chat from the website and even using my iPhone connection via Hotspot it doesn't solve the problem.

I'm sure the settings are ok because they are the same I use on the working computer.

Any help?

Comment: Which OS versions are installed at both Macs (home and work)? Does any computer contain firewall software like Little Snitch or Hands Off!? How likely is it that the employer might block access to facebook?

Comment: hi. both run mountain lion, i have no firewall installed and nothing is blocked on the network. again, i eve tried connecting using my iPhone tethering (bypassing any possible block by the employer), but it doesn't connect

Comment: What is the output of `$ ping -c 4 chat.facebook.com` on the failing Mac? And what is the difference when executing the same command on the Mac where everything is ok?

Comment: yes, i can ping it from here (64 bytes from 69.171.241.10: icmp_seq=0 ttl=242 time=101.384 ms)

Comment: What is the output of `$ telnet chat.facebook.com 5222`. In case the result is like _Connected to chat.facebook.com.
Escape character is '^]'._ you can quit by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> and typing quit + <kbd>Enter</kbd> or just wait 10-15 seconds before the connection closes itselves.

Comment: nope. it doesn't connect! it hangs at "Trying 69.171.241.10..."

Comment: When it doesn't connect, then there is something in between that blocks your connection to the chat.facebook.com server. And it seems to be on your work computer. Because when using your mobile phone to connect your work computer to the internet, it also blocks doesn't connect using telnet, or does it? BTW Over here in Europe chat.facebook.com resolves to 69.171.227.26 and now 69.171.241.10, which connects fine: Trying 69.171.241.10...
Connected to chat.facebook.com.

Answer (score 1):

Your work machine likely blocks port TCP 5222. Or both work network and iPhone mobile operator block port TCP 5222 or chat.facebook.com. Please ensure those are opened on any in between firewall.

Even when the network provider does not actively block port 5222 there can still be issues in the network as [this discussion of 81 posts in length](http://forum.vodafone.co.uk/t5/Network/Vodafone-blocking-port-5222/td-p/860537/page/4) shows.

To be absolutely sure that the issue is network blocking, you could try to setup a VPN connection on the faulty work computer. For instance to your home computer or use the [free VPN demo from usaip.eu](http://www.usaip.eu/en/free_vpn.php).

Answer (score 0):

Re-add the account to Messages app:

1. Delete the account.
2. Add a new account. Account type: Jabber, Account name: `username@chat.facebook.com`. **Leave the server options untouched.**
3. Check if it works.